# Revert failed migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have 7 database and every database has its own migrations file. While running `db:migrate:all` it failed on 6th database on xyz migration file. How do run `db:migrate:down VERSION=xyz' on 6th database. I have tried following combination to revert

1. `db:migrate:all:down VERSION=xyz`
2. `db:migrate:down VERSION=xyz`
3. `db:6th_DB_NAME:migrate:down VERSION=xyz`
4. `db:migrate:6th_DB_NAME:down VERSION=xyz`

All failed. Whats the way around to revert xyz migration?

Comment: I don't see rake running down migrations on certain databases. However, there is a rake to rollback on a specific DB. If that was the last migration on 6th DB, you may roll it back using 'rails db:rollback:6th_DB_NAME'.

Comment: Did u follow this guide? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html

Comment: Have you tried `db:migrate:down:6th_DB_NAME VERSION=xyz`?

Comment: I will try that @SampatBadhe

Comment: @JoelBlum yup i did go through above link but no help from there, but yeah it was quite informative

Comment: Could be that its a missing feature on Rails ...

Comment: @JoelBlum I verified with above rake on my local. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Even if you run `db:migrate:down` it rejects and gives suggestion -> `You're using a multiple database application. To use db:migrate:down you must run the namespaced task with a VERSION. Available tasks are db:migrate:down:primary and db:migrate:down:secondary.`

Comment: @SampatBadhe, interesting! perhaps you two are not on the same Rails version? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JoelBlum possible. I verified it on rails 7.

Comment: @prashant did you get chance to verify above rake?

Comment: @SampatBadhe nope it didn't work got the below error
prashant.arya@% rails db:migrate:down:6thDB VERSION=20220604141631 
D, [2022-06-04T20:16:03.440002 #65892] DEBUG -- : using default configuration
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:down:6thDB' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)

Comment: @prashant could you please run `rails --tasks -a | grep migrate:down` this to check the available down migrations.

Comment: cmd: rails --tasks -a | grep migrate:down
output
`rails db:migrate:down`

Comment: @SampatBadhe I found this command `rails db:migrate:down SCOPE=db_name VERSION=20220516070250`looks like it should serve the purpose unfortunately migrations are found 


`No migration with version number 20220516070250.`

Comment: cool, nice find @prashant I think you wanted to run down migration for `20220604141631` version number.

Comment: @SampatBadhe ignore the VERSION Number, have tried on both.....

Comment: okay @prashant - which rails version you are using?

Comment: @SampatBadhe Rails 5.2.7.1

Comment: oops my bad, I missed to confirm with you earlier. above suggested rakes are available in rails > 6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245336/discussion-between-sampat-badhe-and-prashant).